# How to keep sheep from eating cows grain?

Tags: agriculture

I have 2 cows that go up to a shed and eat grain that I put out every morning, and I also have 5 sheep in the same pasture, that want to eat the grain, so they usually push the cows out of the way, and eat the grain that they dont need. Is there anyway to keeep the sheeps from eating cows grain out of their trough? I've tried raising the trough, but the sheep sut jump up to it and eat.

Comment: This isn't an agricultural site, yet we keep getting agricultural questions. Why not try putting a barbed wire fence around the trough that only the cows are big enough to reach over and get at the food? And you could try getting a more aggressive breed of cow, maybe just one or two, which would stand up for themselves and see off the sheep? Or you could restrict the sheep's access with an electric fence.

Comment: you need to build a fence in front of the trough with opening on the top so only the cows can reach the trough,and you need to restrict the sheeps accsess to the trough from behind and from the sides of the trough.(i think the farmers solved this problem about 10 000 years ago when they started to keep livestock).